# CKEDITOR adding / removing &nbsp; tags

Tags: ckeditor

We are huge fans of CKEditor, but some of our clients are have very particular. We want CKEditor to leave `&nbsp;` chars alone, so we set `fillEmptyBlocks` to false.

However, now if our user adds an `&nbps;` intentionally, it gets removed when it is the only thing within a block. We have investigated a code fix in htmldataprocessor.js, to just shortcircuit the code and return before `cleanBogus` is called, but we really do not want to modify the CKEditor source. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I edited the question a little, but I'm not completely clear on one part of it: "We want CKEditor to leave &nbsp; chars alone, so we set fillEmptyBlocks to false.". Do you mean that you want CKEditor to not add nbsp to empty tags automatically, but you do want to keep intentionally or manually added nbsp's inside blocks?

Comment: Correct - in other words, don't assume, and leave them alone... :)

Comment: So do you think this is possible?